# Angular Directive digest-cycle, best practice

Tags: angularjs, directive, angular-ngmodel

I have a textfield directive that does all sorts of validations based on certain attributes set on the Directive tag.
Based on what initialization of the ngModel this Directive initializes itself.
I have some observers on attributes that try to run functionalities based on setting a value on the attribute, this is sometimes done however when the Directive isn’t fully initialized yet. Thus when initialized isn’t set to true:

```
scope.initialized = false;
ngModelController.$render = function() {
    scope.initialized = true;
    //do stuff
};

attrs.$observe('showValidationMessage', function () {
    //do other stuff
});
```

How do you handle this initialization/defaulting routine? Should I use the compile function for defaulting? Whats the best approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

What I do is to stick watches at the end of my initialise function, so something like this:

```
MyApp.controller('SomeCtrl', function(scope) {
    var self = this;

    /**
     * Initialise the Controller and Scope
    /*
    self.Initialise = function() {
        // Do something here
        // End by setting up watches
    };

    // Initialise the Controller
    self.Initialise();

});
```

This way, by the time you set up your observer, the scope is already initialised. Also note, that if you are using any async calls with `$q`, then you can use `.finally( function callback() { // setup observer } );` to then instantiate your observers.

Comment: Makes perfect sense, however when I put the observer for a specific attribute in this self.initialise function it isn’t triggered while loading the directive as it does. This brings my back to my main question: How do you handle this initialization/defaulting routine?